# Post with PHP cURL request doesn't work, but same request works in POSTMAN

Tags: php, api, curl, post, postman

I am trying to set up a PHP cURL request which i copied exactly from POSTMAN (which is working just fine).

However I get invalid hostname everytime.

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_CAINFO => MSA_CERT,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://xspiint.kusto.windows.net/v1/rest/query",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n  \"db\":\"DallasTelemetry\",\r\n  \"properties\":null,\r\n  \"csl\":\"MaelstromEvents | count\"\r\n}",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "accept: */*",
        "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
        "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "authorization: Bearer ".$access_token,
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "connection: keep-alive",
        "content-length: 30",
        "content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "host: xspiint.kusto.windows.net:443",
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: Remove `"host: xspiint.kusto.windows.net:443",` from headers

Comment: also `"content-length: 30",` and `"connection: keep-alive",` and `"cache-control: no-cache",` and `"content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8",`

Comment: some of them headers are response headers, if you dont know what it does dont add it.

Comment: Lawrence, your fix worked. Do you want to add it as an answer and I will accept?